# How to determine newly inserted data upon using upsert? prisma

Tags: prisma

I have a working code below that inserts a data if it does not exist (but not updates if it exist). In below implementation I am looping `upsert`, and it just works fine.

My question is, how to get those newly inserted data? (exclude data that is already existing). Do have idea how to achieve this, in a shortest way as possible?

I did some research about it and found this [possible github solution](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/3432#discussioncomment-56966), but I don't get the point. Because it also returning data even its already existing.

---

```
this.data = await prisma.$transaction(
  temp.map((provider) =>
    prisma.provider.upsert({
      where: {
        user_id_api_key: {
          user_id: provider.user_id,
          api_key: provider.api_key
        }
      },
      create: provider,
      update: {}
    })
  )
)

console.log(this.data) // it still return data even if its already existing
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and pasting the solution from GitHub here and giving some more explanation to it:

```
const maybeUserId = 42
const user = await prisma.user.upsert({
  create: {
    name: "Nikolas",
    email: "burk@prisma.io"
  },
  update: {
    name: "Nikolas",
    email: "burk@prisma.io",
  },
  where: {
    id: maybeUserId
  }
})

if (user.id === maybeUserId) {
  console.log(`An existing user was updated`)
} else {
  console.log(`A new user was created`)
}
```

If you create/update a user by `id`, you will use the `id` to upsert that particular user in the DB. The returned user either has the same `id` then, meaning the `id` was already in the DB and thus it was an `update` operation, or the user was not in the DB because a new user has been created with a new `id` (generated by the DB).

---

Alternative 1:

```
model User {
  id        String       @id @default(cuid())
  createdAt DateTime     @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime     @updatedAt
  ...
}
```

After the upsert, you can check if the createdAt and the updatedAt dates are the same.

---

Alternative 2:

Adjust the User model in the schema:

```
model User {
  ...
  wasUpdated Boolean @default(false) // false upon create
}
```

Then set it to `true` for the edit and check afterward:

```
const user = await prisma.user.upsert({
  create: {
    email,
    name,
  },
  update: {
    email,
    name,
    wasUpdated: true,
  },
  where: {
    email,
  },  
});

if (user.wasUpdated) {
  console.log('Was updated.);
} else {
  console.log('Was created.);
}
```