# Is there a way to know if a new row was created using Prisma upsert?

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I'm trying to create a new user if it does not exist for that I'm using something like this:

```
  await this.prisma.user.upsert({
    where: {
      email,
    },
    update: {},
    create: {
      email,
      name,
    }
  });
```

Is there a way to know if a new row was created?

In order to know if the user exists previously or if it was created with the upsert

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78006227/1189762

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably need to change the `User` model to include a `wasUpserted` property, then you can query for that property after the `upsert` completes (without making an extra query.) Prisma on its own will make no indication on whether or not an upsert results in the creation OR update of a model - you have to track that on your own OR make a second query after the upsert happens. If you want to avoid the upsert, you'd have to track that on the model you're upserting.

Model:

```
model User {
  // your fields...
  wasUpserted Boolean @default(false) // If the User was created any other way, this will be false
}
```

Code:

```js
const user = await prisma.user.upsert({
  create: {
    email,
    name,
    wasUpserted: true
  },
  update: {},
  where: {
    email,
  },  
});
// user will always equal the user that was EITHER created or updated (in this case no update was performed)
const wasUpserted = user.wasUpserted;
```

Answer (score -1):

you could do

```
const user =  await this.prisma.user.upsert({
    where: {
      email,
    },
    update: {},
    create: {
      email,
      name,
    }
  });
console.log(user)
```

Then log the user to see if the upsert was successful. Alternatively, you could query the database using `findFirst` to retrieve the record that was created.

```
const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
  where: { email }, 
})
console.log(user);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Raphael Etim but what I am trying to do is avoiding the second round trip (findFirst) and for both cases (if the user is created or if the user already exist) it returns the record and  I don't know how to check  if a new record was created or not